# How do I minimize phantomjs memory usage

Tags: memory, phantomjs

Hello there I have a script that generate visits from google to websites.

I run it on my VPS but it only stays 15 minutes before it closes. I noticed that it takes too much ram (aroun 90%) then shut down after.

My question is , how can I reduce the phantomjs consumption.

PS: I can share codes just let me know what you need from me

thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of a full headless browser, consider an HTTP only client, for example curl based. It won't be running JavaScript on pages. or retrieve images/styles/scripts, but it'll consume much less memory and CPU. That said, whatever server side code you're trying to cheat might detect and disrespect that.

Comment: Thanks for answering Seva but how can I integrate that in my code.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to tag someone or to contact him here .

Comment: That's not something you integrate, that's a complete rewrite.

Comment: @hideo I'm curious to have a look, hit me at v#phantomjs.se

Comment: @hideo Once upon a time I had such a problem with PhantomJS. That was probably due to memory leak somewhere in PhantomJS.
I ended up spawning PhantomJS child processes from the main PhantomJS process. How to spawn: http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Drive.close()` and `Drive.quit()` after loops and reopen driver.

Also consider `gc.collect()`